# Select list item <li> of an ordered list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to change the html of the **LI** tag using some kind of jquery code.

The idea is to change the class of the anchor tag from "btnsignin" to another class called "btnsignout" once the user has logged in.

I will use this code inside the ajaxForm success callback function to change the class of anchor tag.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="top-nav">
<ul class="top-nav">
    <li><a id="login-link" class="btnsignin" title="Login">Admin Zone</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What should my code look like? Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the link directly by it's id and then chain the commands to modify the class:

```
$('#login-link').removeClass('btnsignin').addClass('btnsignout');
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("ul.top-nav > li > a").removeClass('btnsignin').addClass('btnsignout');`